# Mix two variables with different lengths in a third variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

How can I mix two variables with different lengths in a third variable? 
Variable1 has 48 entries, variable2 has 16 entries.  Variable3 should have after every third line from variable 1 the entries from variable two in every fourth line.
The length of the two variables could be different, but is always divisible by 3.

```
$i = 0 ; $var3 = $var1 | % { "$_ $($var2[$i])"; $i++ }
```

Doesn't work, because it is for variables of the same length

Example:
$Var1 (48 entries)
Name1
Location1
Country1
Name2
Location2
Country2
.
.
Name16
Location16
Country16

$Var2 (16 entries)
Date1
Date2
.
.
Date16

$Var3 (should have 64 entries)
Name1
Location1
Country1
Date1
.
.
Name16
Location16
Country16
Date16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `$var1` and `$var2` are arrays, and the "entries" are each elements.

If I had to use the method you're using to store variables, I'd do it like this:

```
$var1 = @('Name1','Location1','Country1','Name2','Location2','Country2','Name3','Location3',
'Country3','Name4','Location4','Country4','Name5','Location5','Country5','Name6','Location6',
'Country6','Name7','Location7','Country7','Name8','Location8','Country8','Name9','Location9',
'Country9','Name10','Location10','Country10','Name11','Location11','Country11','Name12',
'Location12','Country12','Name13','Location13','Country13','Name14','Location14','Country14',
'Name15','Location15','Country15','Name16','Location16','Country16');

$var2 = @('Date1','Date2','Date3','Date4','Date5','Date6','Date7','Date8','Date9','Date10',
'Date11','Date12','Date13','Date14','Date15','Date16');

$var3 = @();

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $var2.Count; $i++) {
    $var3 += $var1[$i * 3];
    $var3 += $var1[($i * 3) + 1];
    $var3 += $var1[($i * 3) + 2];
    $var3 += $var2[$i];    
}
```

In reality, I'd probably store this as an array of hashtables, or in a [PSObject/PSCustomObject](http://powershell.org/wp/blog/kb/new-object-psobject-vs-pscustomobject/) as tuples.  Hell, I might even prefer [building a DataTable](http://www.bartsp34ks.nl/news/powershell-how-to-create-a-net-datatable-and-save-it-to-xml-file/) to a flat array.

Comment: thanks, your example works, but how can i change every entry in the variables with an @ at the beginning, the entry in brackets) and ; at the end? Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @Frank I assumed `$var1` and `$var2` were already arrays and you already had them.  You didn't give any information for how those were set.